# Unable to use localdb using entity framework in Windows Form app in Visual studio 2013

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I am trying to create and use a localdb database using entity framework in vs2013 in a windows form application, but I am getting an error. Here are the details:

[image]

[image]

[image]

but when I try to run the program, I get this error:
[image]

[image]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem related to permissions. have you tried to run visual studio as administrator.